# 'wheel' event occurs when doesn't touch the wheel

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have script like this, It shows the message in console when wheel works with ctrlkey(for mac command key)

```
const handleWheel = (e) =>{
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey){
        console.log("handle wheel is called");
    }
}

useEffect(() =>{
    ref_wrapper_div.current.addEventListener('wheel',handleWheel,{passive:false});
});
```

Now something strange happens.

1. command with mouse wheel -> message appears
2. release the wheel  -> nothing happens
3. push command key -> message appears

why this 3 happens?

How can I prevent this?

Comment: "release the wheel" maybe you are trying to capture a click event and not a wheel/scroll event?